# Codename One POST pic to ocr.space

Tags: json, api, ocr, codenameone

I'm having problems posting an image to [ocr.space](https://ocr.space/ocrapi). Their api supports files, urls, and base64images. The only one I'm not open to is the url.

The error I get when posting a file is "It's not the right kind of file".

How can I post either a file or a base64image? Here is the code I have:

```
public void pictureUploads(final Callback<String> resultURL) {
String picture = Capture.capturePhoto(1024, -1);
if(picture!=null){
    String filestack = "https://api.ocr.space/parse/image";
    MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest() {
       protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException  {
          JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
          Map<String, Object> result = jp.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
          System.out.println("" + result);              
          String url = (String)result.get("ParsedText");
          if(url == null) {

             resultURL.onError(null, null, 1, result.toString());
             return;
          }
          resultURL.onSucess(url);
       }
    };
    request.setUrl(filestack);

    try {
        request.setPost(true);
        request.addData("file", picture, "image/jpg"); 
        request.setContentType("image/jpeg");

        request.addArgument("apikey", "helloWorld");
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
    } catch(IOException err) {
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, I needed to add this line after the addData: request.setFilename("file", "ocr.jpeg");